# Проблемы с нахождением элементов на html странице twiter selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, бот, twitter

Пробую найти кнопки 'follow' но не получается:

```
driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('u-hiddenVisually')[0].click()
driver.find_elements_by_class_name("u-hiddenVisually")[0].click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@u-hiddenVisually]').click()
```

> raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
>   selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such
>   element: Unable to locate element:
>   {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@u-hiddenVisually]"}   (Session
>   info: chrome=71.0.3578.98)   (Driver info: chromedriver=2.43.600210
>   (68dcf5eebde37173d4027fa8635e332711d2874a),platform=Windows NT
>   6.1.7601 SP1 x86)

на странице к примеру:https://twitter.com/TheVenusProject/followers
как найти все кнопки 'Follow' и рандомно нажать на 5 из страницы?
Если кто знает годную ссылку для создании бота твитера пошаговый, скиньте плиз

Comment: Как вы составляете XPath, вручную? Если да, и если вы пользуетесь Chrome, то: откройте твиттер > наведите курсор на кнопку "follow" > клик правой кнопкой мыши > Inspect (не знаю как  по-русски этот пункт называется, последняя строка). Откроется окно  с исходным кодом с выделенным элементом, отвечающим за кнопку. Снова клик правой кнопкой на этом выделенном элементе> копировать > копировать XPath. Ну и попробуйте использовать этот XPath в своем коде.

Answer (score -1):

это кнопка "Follow"

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="page-container"]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/ul/li[6]/div/div/span[2]/button[1]/span[1]')
```